# Stored procedure to insert concatenated string into table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables, `ParentPayor` and `ChildPayor`.

`ParentID` is the primary key in `ParentPayor` and `ParentID` is a foreign key in the `ChildPayor` table. The `ChildPayor` table has a column `State`.

I would like to create a stored procedure that concatenates each `State` in the `ChildPayor` table, and inserts the string into the `ParentPayor` column `States`, where `ChildPayor.ParentID = ParentPayor.ParentID`.

I just discovered `STRING_AGG` to concatenate:

```
    STRING_AGG (State, ',') 
FROM ChildPayors AS States 
WHERE ParentPayorID = 32
```

[image]

But I would like to be able to concatenate all `State`s within the `ChildPayor`, and insert into `ParentPayor` where the `ParentID`s match. Does this make sense?

Something like (I know this is incorrect):

```
SELECT STRING_AGG (State, ',') 
FROM ChildPayors, ParentPayors AS States 
WHERE ParentPayors.ParentPayorID = ChildPayors.ParentPayorID

INSERT INTO ParentPayors(States) 
VALUES (States)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Seems more sensible to keep the database normalized and leave it only in the one table. When you need the info just query it, perhaps using a view

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will often use CROSS APPLY to calculate intermediate values. Try something like:

```
DECLARE @ParentPayor TABLE (ParentID INT, ParentName VARCHAR(100), States VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT @ParentPayor
VALUES
    (1, 'AAA', null),
    (2, 'BBB', null),
    (3, 'CCC', null),
    (4, 'DDD', null)

DECLARE @ChildPayor TABLE (ChildID INT, ParentID INT, StateName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @ChildPayor
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'New York'),
    (2, 2, 'Texas'),
    (3, 2, 'Virginia'),
    (4, 2, 'California'),
    (5, 4, 'Virginia'),
    (6, 4, 'New York')

UPDATE P
SET States = S.States
FROM @ParentPayor P
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT States = STRING_AGG(C.StateName, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY C.StateName)
    FROM @ChildPayor C
    WHERE C.ParentID = P.ParentID
) S

SELECT *
FROM @ParentPayor P
```

Output:

| ParentID | ParentName | States |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | New York |
| 2 | BBB | California, Texas, Virginia |
| 3 | CCC | (null) |
| 4 | DDD | New York, Virginia |

The UPDATE statement above would then become the body of your stored procedure.

On further reflection, a subselect could also be used. The following JOIN could be used in place of the CROSS APPLY:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C.ParentID, States = STRING_AGG(C.StateName, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY C.StateName)
    FROM @ChildPayor C
    GROUP BY C.ParentID
) S ON S.ParentID = P.ParentID
```